# Dual relay motion sensor, only one relay active?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, motion-sensor

I have a bathroom with a fan and a light in it, the light is on one switch and the fan on another. Since the fan was an add on, they were put in a single gang box with two switches.

I want to make it so the fan is motion sensor activated, but the light not (too bright when you get up in the middle of the night). I've seen dual relay motion sensors out there, but to override the motion, you have to actually let the light come on. Is there some way to make it so only one relay is motion active(the fan) and the other manual only?

Comment: It'd be worth checking with your local building code before doing this. Often, the fan needs to be switched separately in such a way it can run w/o the light on and for a prolonged amount of time after anyone exits the bathroom. This is to allow the fan to continue to exhaust the moisture out of the room.

Comment: A possible solution if no device is found is to add a cut in box to the ceiling that will hold a single relay motion sensor that will control the fan separately from the light. That would of course depend on a constant hot that you can get your hands on and extend if need be.